# How is Azure database hour calculated?

Tags: azure

I have a "STANDARD S0 DATABASE DAYS - SQL DATABASE" instance under a Pay-As-You-Go subscription. I noticed the database instance is billed by days regardless of if my web site uses it. I can tell my web site didn't use the database for the past few days by log files but the total database day is increasing. When I was selecting the database plan, the database rates are listed in a hour rate and that gave me an impression that the database usage is measured by hours. Am I missing anything obvious here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Database is billed by hours of existence and not by usage.

Taken from the [SQL Database FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-faq/#how-does-the-usage-of-sql-database-show-up-on-my-bill)

> For example, if a database exists for 12 hours in a month, your bill
>   will show usage of 0.5 days.
>
> You are billed for each hour a database exists using the highest
>   service tier + performance level that applied during that hour,
>   regardless of usage or whether the database was active for less than
>   an hour. For example, if you create a single database and delete it 5
>   minutes later your bill will reflect a charge for 1 database hour.

Answer (score 0):

Serverless is a compute tier for single databases in Azure SQL Database that automatically scales compute based on workload demand and bills for the amount of compute used per second. The serverless compute tier also automatically pauses databases during inactive periods when only storage is billed and automatically resumes databases when activity returns. The serverless compute tier is available in the General Purpose service tier and currently in preview in the Hyperscale service tier.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKMA0.jpg)